# how to center an item in the list of <ul> in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

here's some code I have put on my navbar

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" >
     <ul id="bloglist" style="text-align:center;">
         <li><a href="#"> Fashion </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Food </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Travel </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> LifeStyle </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> History </a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

how do i put those items in the center? i already use align center but the list is not inline what is the actual css code that will put all the list in the center inline? thank you sooo much

Answer (score 0):

Try in your CSS file

```
.bloglist li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a centered justified list in line? Try Bootstrap's justified navbar: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/